# routeEnhancers for non-existent news url

Tags: typo3, tx-news, typo3-9.x

I configured routeEnhancers for news and everything seems to work. My url looks user-friendly domain.my/news/details/something-new-242. Now I want to check what happen when someone add some characters to my url fe domain.my/news/details/something-new-242-2ddwdwedw

typo3 throws error: Parameter "acec1fc0ac7e1adfbcd522115dc07925" for route "tx_news_pi1_0" must match "[^/]++" ("" given) to generate a corresponding URL.

What I expected was 404 error page.

My question is how to modify routeEnhancers to throw 404

```
routeEnhancers:

  NewsPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/{news_post}', _controller: 'News::detail', _arguments: {'news_post': 'news'} }
      - { routePath: '/{tag_name}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'tag_name': 'overwriteDemand/tags'} }
      - { routePath: '/{category}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'category': 'overwriteDemand/categories'} }
      - { routePath: '/{page}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
      - { routePath: '/{year}/{month}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'year': 'overwriteDemand/year', 'month': 'overwriteDemand/month' } }
      - { routePath: '/{year}/{month}/{day}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'year': 'overwriteDemand/year', 'month': 'overwriteDemand/month', 'day': 'overwriteDemand/day' } }
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    aspects:
      news_post:
        type: PersistedPatternMapper
        tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_news'
        routeFieldPattern: '^(?P<path_segment>.+)-(?P<uid>\d+)$'
        routeFieldResult: '{path_segment}-{uid}'
      tag_name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_tag'
        routeFieldName: 'slug'
      category:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'sys_category'
        routeFieldName: 'slug'
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '1000'
```

Answer (score 0):

Just more thing you have missed which is 404 redirect configuration Try this,

```
routeEnhancers:

  NewsPlugin:
    type: Extbase
    extension: News
    plugin: Pi1
    routes:
      - { routePath: '/{news_post}', _controller: 'News::detail', _arguments: {'news_post': 'news'} }
      - { routePath: '/{tag_name}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'tag_name': 'overwriteDemand/tags'} }
      - { routePath: '/{category}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'category': 'overwriteDemand/categories'} }
      - { routePath: '/{page}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'page': '@widget_0/currentPage'} }
      - { routePath: '/{year}/{month}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'year': 'overwriteDemand/year', 'month': 'overwriteDemand/month' } }
      - { routePath: '/{year}/{month}/{day}', _controller: 'News::list', _arguments: {'year': 'overwriteDemand/year', 'month': 'overwriteDemand/month', 'day': 'overwriteDemand/day' } }
    defaultController: 'News::list'
    aspects:
      news_post:
        type: PersistedPatternMapper
        tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_news'
        routeFieldPattern: '^(?P<path_segment>.+)-(?P<uid>\d+)$'
        routeFieldResult: '{path_segment}-{uid}'
      tag_name:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'tx_news_domain_model_tag'
        routeFieldName: 'slug'
      category:
        type: PersistedAliasMapper
        tableName: 'sys_category'
        routeFieldName: 'slug'
      page:
        type: StaticRangeMapper
        start: '1'
        end: '1000'

errorHandling:
  -
    errorCode: '404'
    errorHandler: Page
    errorContentSource: 't3://page?uid=14'
```

This is what you want I guess, Isn't it?

Comment: hi. I already had this in my config. It does not solve problem with wrong news url